# How does the security of AES change if we allow multiple uses in a row? How does it change if we limit the key space? And introduce a filter function?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, attack, complexity, meet-in-the-middle-attack

$$f_0 = A$$
$$f_{n+1}=AES(f_n,k_n)$$
$$f_i = B$$

For given 128-bit values $A, B$ we want to find a chain of suitable 128-bit keys $k_1$ to $k_i$.
The total length $i$ is undetermined. Every valid key chain size gets accepted.

---

***How long will it take?***
If we limit $i=1$ it would be equal to the normal use case.
$$B = AES(A,k_1)$$
Finding the 128-bit key $k_1$ for given $A, B$ would take in mean $\approx 2^{126}$ steps ([wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)).

But as soon as we allow another chain element it will get much easier.
e.g. for $i=2$ it would be
$$B = AES(AES(A,k_1),k_2)$$
To find $k_1, k_2$ we can just start from both directions and generate values $a_m, b_n$
$$AES(A,k_{1,m}) = a_m$$
$$AES^{-1}(B,k_{2,n}) = b_n$$
until we find some intersection of their value sets $\{a_m\}$ and $\{b_n\}$. In mean this should take $\approx \sqrt{\pi} \cdot 2^{64}$ steps ([stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468469/two-artists-want-to-paint-all-sand-grains-in-2-colors-they-stop-if-one-artist-p)).
This would be not secure anymore.

---

***Can we improve the security by limiting the key space?***
To avoid those $\approx 2^{64}$ $a_m, b_n$ we could reduce the possible options of progression by limiting the key space to e.g. $2^{32}$ values. For AES128 the other 96 values could be e.g. always $0$.
With this we can only produce $\approx 2^{32}$ different values out of $A$ and $B$ each. They won't match up for most pairs $A, B$.
However if we increase the chain length to $i=4$ every of those $2^{32}$ values can again produce another $2^{32}$ values.
In total $\approx 2^{64}$ which makes an intersection much more likely again.

--> **it can not**

---

***How about a filter function?***
Given any $C,D,k$ in
$$ D = AES(C,k)$$
We call this connection/key valid if a filter function $g = 1$
$$ g ( C,D,k) =
\begin{cases}
    1              & \text{in rare cases } 1:2^{24} \text{combinations from } C,D,k\\
    0              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Given this, starting from $A, B$ we can only produce about $2^{8}$ most likely new values but have to compute $2^{32}$ different keys for it. 
We have to increase the total chain length $i$ to $> 16$ to reach those $\sqrt{\pi}\cdot 2^{64}$ necessary members for an intersection.

For $i=16$ with in mean $\approx 2^{64}$ members for both sides we would have to compute AES $\approx 2^{88}$ times.

$2^{88}$ no high security but far better then $2^{64}$. Example values could be tweaked for more security.

---

***Questions***
Are those step counts (round about) correct? Or does exist any significant faster way to do it?
If e.g. the keys can only be a small number of different values are there any security shortcomings here?

---

*Further details:*
Different to usual AES use case we do not want to encrypt any plain text message here. The goal is to encrypt the relation in between 128-bit values for everyone. So AES is in ECB mode here. 
There need to be:

- a fast way to proof if a chain connection is correct (< 1 sec at normal desktop PC)
- Given $A$ it should be not too easy/hard to find any connection (> 1sec, < 10h)
- Given $A$ and $B$ it should be as hard as possible to find a connection in between them
- (The total number of different values (like $A,B$) should be a small as possible. I think it can't be much less than 128 bit)
- (edited: need to be symmetric. If A->B is known B->A will use the same keys in opposite order)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent meet-in-the-middle attacks, the most straight-forward approach would to make the 'forward' direction noninvertable, such as:

$$f_{n+1} = AES( f_n, k_n ) \oplus f_n$$

From what I can see, that change still meets your requirements...

Comment: Thank you for the post but I'm sorry I forgot to mention this. It need to be invertible using the same keys in opposite order.

Comment: But btw for $i=1$ would this be less secure than normal AES? This function can not reach every value B.

Comment: @J.Doe: actually, with the original algorithm with $i=1$, you also cannot reach every value $B$ with a fixed $A$; $\text{AES}(A, K)$ is not (unlikely to be) a permutation on $K$

Comment: thanks for the hint. Did not thought about this. Given a random 128-bit input $A$ the expected proportion of values in reach using every 128-bit key $K$ should only be $1-e^{-1}$ or $\approx 63\%$